# Are any well known conjectures proved to be provable or falsifiable and yet not proved or falsified?

Tags: formal-proofs

Are there any well known conjectures that are proved to be provable or falsifiable and yet not proved or falsified? Let me give an example. Consider the statement:

"There is a natural number $x$ which has property $p$".

Now suppose we could prove that, should the number $x$ exist, it must be lower than $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$.

Then it means that we know that the statement can be proved or falsified by checking each number $x$ from $1$ to $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$.

Therefor we have an algorithm for the proof (or an algorithm to falsify the statement). It's just that it would take too long to run. And we don't know the result.

What got me thinking was if we had a statement like "If there is an exceptional zero of the Riemann function then it's imaginary value would have upper limit of $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$", then this might be a proof (or a falsification test) even though it would take too long to run.

Comment: [Weak Goldbach conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture) was historically one such example.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. For example some theorems we don't even know if they are provable so this is an example of proof of provability!

Comment: Ah, number theory is full of such examples. The smallest number where Mertens conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture) breaks is unknown and is really big. Cf. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvMGZb0Suyc

Comment: I think the question should be, "Are there any well known *conjectures/propositions* that are proved to be provable or falsifiable and yet not proved or falsified?". The word proof in stead of "conjectures/propositions" doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Good point